# Display first and last element on foreach

Tags: php, date, datetime, foreach

I have this little part:

```
foreach($events as $key=>$event){   
    if($event->order ==  $orderss){

        $id = $event->id;
        $date = new DateTime($event->start);
        $start = $date->format('H:i Y-m-d ');
        $date_end = new DateTime($event->end);
        $end = $date_end->format('H:i Y-m-d ');
        echo $start.' - '.$end.'<br>';

    }       
}
```

And it's returning the next values:

```
18:00 2015-04-29 - 19:00 2015-04-29 

19:00 2015-04-29 - 20:00 2015-04-29 

20:00 2015-04-29 - 21:00 2015-04-29 

21:00 2015-04-29 - 22:00 2015-04-29
```

AND

```
11:00 2015-05-11 - 12:00 2015-05-11

12:00 2015-05-11 - 13:00 2015-05-11 

13:00 2015-05-11 - 14:00 2015-05-11
```

My question is if I can tak over the foreach the value `18:00 2015-04-29` AND `22:00 2015-04-29`

`11:00 2015-05-11`  AND `14:00 2015-05-11` ?

This goes inside a table column, on foreach creates a new column with those dates, if I use $key==0, then only the first column fills up and the rest, stays empty

Comment: so only display the first and last values?

Comment: Use a counter ? You'll output when your counter is at 0 and count($events) -1

Comment: yes, the fist date and the last date

Comment: That goes inside a table, where are other dates, and if I trie with $key == 0, only return the first date, and fills up the first column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$key`. Assuming `$event` is an array with an index from `0` to `count($event)-1`:

```
foreach($events as $key=>$event){   
    if($event->order ==  $orderss && (($key == 0) || ($key == count($event)-1))){
        $id = $event->id;
        $date = new DateTime($event->start);
        $start = $date->format('H:i Y-m-d ');
        $date_end = new DateTime($event->end);
        $end = $date_end->format('H:i Y-m-d ');
        echo $start.' - '.$end.'<br>';
     }       
  }
```

Comment: That's only returning the index 0 of the foreach, this is inside a table, I need to return the first date on each column of the table

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the first  and last values of the array you could use array_shift and array_pop.

```
$start=new DateTime(array_shift( $events ));
$end=new DateTime(array_pop($events));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use end($array); for the last element and for the first element reset($array);

Answer (score 0):

For first value -

```
$first = current($events);
```

For last value -

```
$last = end($events);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the last element
end($events); $last_key = key($events);
//Reset and get the first element
reset($events); $first_key = key($events);

//Now get the dates
$first_date = $events[$first_key];
$last_date = $events[$last_key];

echo $first_date . '<br />' . $last_date;
```

I get the last one first because I'm resetting the pointer afterwards anyway. This way you also get the keys which might come in handy later.